# Fetch objects from Coredata using NSDate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have 10 records in database. I want to fetch the record where date == mydate.

For eg, there are 2 records in database, which has date of `502479617.512` (in milliseconds).

I am converting the above date to NSDate using

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:502479617.512].
```

I am getting `2016-12-03 17:40:17 +0000`

I have date parameter '502479617.500' which returns same NSDate `2016-12-03 17:40:17 +0000`.

But when i try to fetch from coredata, i am getting 0 objects. It is because of milliseconds in the database. How can i discard milliseconds to fetch the records which has same date, time and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate properties will be stored as NSDate attributes, unless the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" checkbox is marked.

In that case, the core data attribute will be stored as a NSTimeInterval (double).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either of two ways:

First, you could eliminate the seconds decimals when storing the NSDate. It could be automated by overriding `didSet` for the property. You could also simply do it wherever you do the conversion you describe.

Alternatively, you could specify an interval of one second when fetching. Your fetch request would then need a predicate of this kind:

```
NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ && date < %@", aDate, aDate.addingTimeInterval(60))
```

Objective-C

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ && date < %@", 
     aDate, [aDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save it as NSString. Then convert back to double when you need it.